# Render HTML in React Native

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app, I am pulling in JSON data that has raw HTML elements like this: `<p>This is some text. Let&#8217;s figure out...</p>`

I've added the data to a view in my app like this:

`<Text>{this.props.content}</Text>`

The problem is that the HTML comes out raw, it does not render like it would in a browser. Is there a way to get my JSON data to look like it would in a browser, inside my app view?

Comment: in React, there's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html) to display HTML.

I can't test it now, but it could work also with Native.

Comment: Actually I tried that:  `<Text dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.content }} ></Text>` didn't work unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: check this: https://gist.github.com/jsdf/7f983f2cd955fd75d6cc

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview seems to be the latest component to achieve this.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**Edit Jan 2021**: The React Native docs currently recommend React Native WebView:

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: '<p>Here I am</p>' }}
/>
```

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview

If you don't want to embed a `WebView`, there are also third party libraries to render HTML into native views:

1. [`react-native-render-html`](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/)
2. [`react-native-htmlview`](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview)

---

Edit March 2017: the `html` prop has been deprecated. Use `source` instead:

```
<WebView source={{html: '<p>Here I am</p>'}} />
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#html

Thanks to [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5036757/justin) for pointing this out.

---

Edit Feb 2017: the PR was accepted a while back, so to render HTML in React Native, simply:

```
<WebView html={'<p>Here I am</p>'} />
```

---

Original Answer:

I don't think this is currently possible. The behavior you're seeing is expected, since the Text component only outputs... well, text. You need another component that outputs HTML - and that's the [WebView](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#content).

Unfortunately right now there's no way of just directly setting the HTML on this component:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/506

However I've just created [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/506) which implements a basic version of this feature so hopefully it'll land in some form soonish.

Comment: Awesome Colin, thanks for doing that! I'll keep an eye on the github issue.

Comment: According to the docs at versions 0.42 (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#html) the html property has been deprecated. It now says that it should be used with the source prop instead. `<WebView source={{ html: '<p>Here I am</p>' }} />`.

Comment: Docs now say `Note that static HTML will require setting originWhitelist to ["*"].` Although I can't get this to work.

Comment: Man this looks great, except I pasted `<WebView source={{html: '<p>Here I am</p>'}} />` into my component and it's not rendering anything! Help! (I'll try `react-native-render-html` in the meantime)

Comment: @JonathanTuzman You need to set `flex` and `flexdirection` to the View that is wrapping your WebView like `<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column'}}>{"put your WebView here"}</view>`.

Comment: [react-native WebView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/webview.html) is deprecated now: Use [react-native-community/react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) instead.

Answer (score 17):

I found this component. https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview

This component takes HTML content and renders it as native views, with customisable style and handling of links, etc.

Comment: HTML styling with CSS does not work with react-native-htmlview. If that's an issue, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Don't recommend it too.

Comment: It is now 2019 and I see no modern, recently updated, useable option for this!

Comment: Actually it does help me for my purpose rendering html with height inside scrollview, thanks

Comment: @RenatoBack If you need inline CSS support, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899575/2779871

Comment: I'm not sure why you're offering me CSS support, since I never asked for it. Anyways, thanks @JulesSam.Randolph

Comment: @RenatoBack "HTML styling with CSS does not work with react-native-htmlview." (Sep 6 '16 at 22:56)

Answer (score 16):

A pure JavaScript react-native component that renders your HTML into 100% native views. It's made to be extremely customizable and easy to use and aims at being able to render anything you throw at it.

[react-native-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html)

Using this component will improve your application memory footprint and performance when compared to embedded `WebViews`.

**Install**

`npm install react-native-render-html --save or yarn add react-native-render-html`

**Basic usage**

```js
import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";
import RenderHTML from "react-native-render-html";

const html = `
  <h1>This HTML snippet is now rendered with native components !</h1>
  <h2>Enjoy a webview-free and blazing fast application</h2>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dHLmxfO.jpg?2" />
  <em style="textAlign: center;">Look at how happy this native cat is</em>
`;

export default function App() {
  // Allow images to scale to available width
  // with contentWidth prop.
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <RenderHTML contentWidth={width} source={{ html }} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

[`RenderHTML` Props reference](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/renderhtmlprops)

You may customize the style of elements via class names, tags, and you can even [register custom renders for tags](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/docs/guides/custom-renderers). More info on [the official website](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/).

Comment: I think that as of version 6.0.0 of react-native-render-html the line should actually be: 
 <RenderHTML contentWidth={width} source={{ html : html }} />

Answer (score 3):

i uses Js function ***replace*** simply.

```
<Text>{item.excerpt.rendered.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")}</Text>
```

Comment: Could you add some information about what this does or how / why it works?

Comment: This wont render HTML it just strips out any html content.

Answer (score 2):

React Native has updated the WebView component to allow for direct html rendering. Here's an example that works for me

```
var htmlCode = "<b>I am rendered in a <i>WebView</i></b>";

<WebView
  ref={'webview'}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  style={styles.webView}
  html={htmlCode} />
```

Comment: The html prop is [now deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html). Use the source prop instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <WebView ref={'webview'} automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false} source={require('../Assets/aboutus.html')} />
```

This worked for me :) I have html text aboutus file.

Answer (score 2):

```
import HTML from "react-native-render-html";
var htmlCode = "<b>I am <i>Italic</i></b>";


<HTML source={{html: htmlCode}}/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `WebView` component was not rendering for me HTML snippets, like

```html
<b>hello</b>, world!
```

But if I would enclose the HTML snippet in a document, like the example below, then it did actually render the document:

```
<View style={styles.accContent}>
    <WebView source={{html: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style="font-size: 3rem">${data.content}</body></html>`}} />
</View>
```