# React XP - How do I render raw HTML text with custom styling?

Tags: react-native, reactxp

In react-native, I could just simply use `WebView`, how do I do it in ReactXP without using 3rd party library ?

Like the one discussed here [Render HTML in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native)