# Invariant Violation: View Config not Found for name li

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something basic here, but I can't figure it out. I've been following [this](http://jasonjl.me/blog/2015/04/18/rendering-list-of-elements-in-react-with-jsx/) tutorial to render a list of elements, but I'm getting a "View Config not Found for name li" error, and for any other HTML element that I attempt to use in render(). Not sure where I'm going wrong here as all other similar questions had solutions that I've already included in my code (like including a return statement), so any advice would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import ReactList from 'react-list';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Navigator, AppRegistry, TextInput, 
TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
const { createGame, addUserToGame } = require('./requestors');

class Players extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        players: [{
            name: 'Player1',
        }, {
            name: 'Player2',
        }],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ul>
        {this.state.players.map(player => <li>{player.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      );
  }
}

module.exports = Players;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render HTML in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native)

Comment: Read the official documentation carefully. And it is a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

you cant render html component in react-native

Comment: why negative voting?  that's true you cant render html element in native unless you use webView

Comment: because while flatly true, it lacks any substance to push either the original asker or anyone else forward to an actual solution.  It reminds me of the Babylon 5 quote - "While all answers are replies, not all replies are answers."