# How to connect special symbols like &nbsp; &yen; in react-native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I want connect a string use " ` " ,  and wish " & yen; " will show as "¥",   the code like  below :

```
let str=`${period} per (money：&yen;${money})`
```

but did not work for me ,

by the way,I write it use react-native

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse HTML Entities you can use the npm module [html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities).

Here is a working example:

```
import { Html5Entities } from 'html-entities'; 

render() {
    const entities = new Html5Entities();
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View>
        <Text> {entities.decode('&yen')} </Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image: Example output]

Comment: @zzq you're welcome. Could you please also mark my answer as accepted. (Press the check icon beside my answer). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript native method like

```
let formattedMoney = new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(money);
let str=`${period} per (money：${formattedMoney})`
```

Comment: I  use react-native,  it dose not work, but pure javascript  test is ok .