# How to render HTML in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am getting the html response from the api as shown below. I want to render the  text and open the url on click of the text that is given in the response.

```
"Details": "<span style=\"font-family: Georgia; font-size: 24px;\"><em><span style=\"color: #0070c0;\"><a href=\"http://the.company.com/apr19/default.aspx\" target=\"_blank\">Click here to view News.</a></span></em></span>"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render HTML in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `WebView` as HTML renderer like this,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class MyInlineWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>' }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[See official docs here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md)

Comment: Please note that docs you are reffering to are deprecated. [react-native-community/react-native-webview fork](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) should be used for new projects.

Comment: I also tried with WebView which is now a part of react-native-community but I got the error it does not exist in Haste map. I also linked it manually and for ios I installed pod but it still gives an error.

Comment: @JaydeepGalani  is there a way to extract url from such response.

Answer (score 2):

use this package [react-native-render-html](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html)

extremely customizable and easy to use and aims at being able to render anything you throw at it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';

const htmlContent = `
    <h1>This HTML snippet is now rendered with native components !</h1>
    <h2>Enjoy a webview-free and blazing fast application</h2>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dHLmxfO.jpg?2" />
    <em style="textAlign: center;">Look at how happy this native cat is</em>
`;

export default class Demo extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <HTML html={htmlContent} imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width} />
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this method but for some it is working while others it displays with HTML tags

Comment: While it works, for some reason there's a deprecation warning.