# Get HTML Data,HTML Tags from API in React-Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm making mobile app with React-Native and i wanna get data from my API.But my API's datas , databases has html tags (you can see them in images which i shared) and some character codes because there are also Turkish characters.I already was using this API from my web site and there was no problem but when i try to get data to my react native app , it is getting data as a plain text as you see in my images.How can i get this datas without problem[image][image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29365213/5909026

Answer (score 1):

It's called HTML entity. This is the code that works on browser (not on your case)

```
var decodeEntities = (function() {
  // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
  var element = document.createElement('div');

  function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
      // strip script/html tags
      str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
      str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
      element.innerHTML = str;
      str = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }

    return str;
  }

  return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();
```

The code are copied from here [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

But it only works on the browser because the browser are automatically translate the characters for you.

---

I don't think passing around unserialized data like this is a good idea. **You might want to encode data in server side using url encode or something then decode it in the react-native side**

---

Reference

- https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp

Answer (score 1):

Actually i solved it with this : https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html
Thanks