# Is it possible to use <div> tag in React Native tag?

Tags: react-native

Now I am using firebase JS SDK to use phone authentication. I followed the `web method`.

Here is my code:

```
  handleClick = () => {
    this.state.verify_otp = "flex";
    this.state.register = "none";
    this.recaptcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha1");
    this.number = this.state.phone;
  };
```

.

```
<View
    style={{
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flex: 1,
        display: this.state.captcha,
    }}
>
    <div>
        <div id="recaptcha1"></div>
    </div>
</View>
```

Is it possible to use a  tag in react-native code?

Answer (score 3):

No, not natively. React Native doesn't support direct HTML, as it is not a web framework.

For rendering HTML in React Native, see [Render HTML in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to use html tags in react-native

edit: list of basic RN components https://reactnative.dev/docs/components-and-apis#basic-components

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use the `<div>` element inside a react native component because React Native does not have a DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately its not possible. Div is an HTML element which can be read by Browser. For mobile app,  Its `View`

However you can build your own `div`

```
class Div extends Component {  //or Class Span extends Component

  static propTypes = {
      style : PropTypes.obj
      onClick : PropTypes.func   // ...
  }

  render (){
        return (
        <View>
        
    /* whatever is needed to pass everything through  ... */
  
       </View>
 )    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could use [react-native-render-html](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html#readme) to achieve like follow.
(if couldn't work have to install react-native-webview)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';


const htmlContent = `
    <h1>This HTML snippet is Using react-native-render-html !</h1>
    <h2>Trying many tag to render html</h2>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fJ71V9b.jpg" />
    <div>Here is what you want to add!!!!!<div>`
    ;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <HTML html={htmlContent} imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width} />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  } 
});
```

[Code example on snack](https://snack.expo.io/wMg7YAAlO)