# How to use html "code" and "pre" tag in React-Native

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an application for programmers in React Native.
I am very new to React-native, so only thing that I understood was to use `<Text>` instead of `<span>` and use `<View>` instead of `<div>` blah blah blah..

However, I want to include the actual code inside the React-Native app. I came across that I could not use `<pre>` nor `<code>` and instead I get the following error

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `code` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.
```

Help is needed. If there is a library that does this let me know also.
Waiting for React-native experts!

Comment: Please share the component where you're using the `code` or `pre` tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render HTML in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native)

Comment: @JakeWorth I do not have specific code yet but I want to use something like this in React ```return ( <div><code>{javascript code goes here} </code></div>) ``` to like this in React-Native ```return (<View><Text>{something goes here}</Text> </View>)```