# How to get text inside a div or span in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently receive a data like this

```
  [
    "<span style=\"color: rgb(61, 57, 53); font-weight: 700; white-space: normal; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);\">CONVEYOR SYSTEM CHECKLIST</span>",
    "<span style=\"font-weight: 700; white-space: normal; background-color: rgb(244, 245, 245);\">X-62-11</span>",
    "<span style=\"font-weight: 700; white-space: normal; background-color: rgb(244, 245, 245);\">CONDITION</span>",
    "<span style=\"font-weight: 700; white-space: normal; background-color: rgb(244, 245, 245);\">REMARK</span>"
  ],
```

So i wonder can we only get the text of this span or div, like above data will be

```
[CONVEYOR SYSTEM CHECKLIST,X-62-11,CONDITION, REMARK ]
```

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with react native per say. It's just string parsing for contents

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native) will help you