# dangerouslySetInnerHTML equiavalent for React Native?

Tags: react-native, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

How can I get the same result in React Native's `<Text></Text>` for the place of the code written below in React-web-app:

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHtml={{ __html: myString }} />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render HTML in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native)

Comment: I think you may not understand how RN works. It effectively executes with native components. Since native iOS/Android do not use HTML, the idea of rendering HTML makes no sense. Stuff that depends on the browser is not portable to RN.

Comment: @NickBailey Yes I am new at playing with html's inside react native. Therefore I am asking a workaround solution for that, or how to effectively render an Html written API response

Comment: @NickBailey I've observed that post before, but I thought maybe some new features were added since 2021. Probably I should embed webview then?

Comment: Yep. Webview is the only option.

Comment: @NickBailey not quite. There are usecases. I am trying to use my native app on the browser. I would love to just render stuff directly without having to use `WebView` related stuff which is trully bugy in react native web.