# How to make specific text of a string bold if i marked in some way in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

*Guys sorry for my English it's my second language*.

So There's a string with the following text:

```
**Lorem** ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
```

How to replace "**" characters with `<b>` and `</b>` tags or `<div>` and `</div>` tags with React native, so i can **output** it like this:

```
<b>Lorem</b> ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
```

I tried to start bold text with `**` and end with `/*`, and then replace `**` with `<b>` and `/*` with `</b>` using replace method:

`str.replace("/*", "</b>").replace("**", "<b>")`

but i got only string like this:

`<b>Lorem</b> ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.`.

It's problematic because I'm using React native, which outputs only like string. It'd work in PHP.

Previously thanks!

Comment: you have to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) after replacing them (use cautiously as the name itself suggest ) .... btw your English is really good - no apologies required as no one is an expert and native though

Comment: [Render HTML in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native) to use something similar to dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React Native

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like the below code.

Step-wise details:

1. Split the text string around `**` to create an array `arr` of `string`.
2. The string inside the `**...**` will be at odd indices in `arr` array.
3. So, wrap strings at odd indices with bold-styled `Text` component and other strings at even indices(i.e. which are outside the `**...**` block) with simple `Text` component.
4. Append these `Text` components to an array.
5. Render this array of `Text` components in another `Text` component to display all of them as a single component on the same line.

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

function App() {
  const text =
    "**Lorem** ipsum dolor sit, *amet consectetur **adipisicing** elit.";

  function getSmartBold() {
    // Split the text around **
    const arr = text.split("**");

    // Here we will store an array of Text components
    const newTextArr = [];

    // Loop over split text
    arr.forEach((element, index) => {
      // If its an odd element then it is inside **...** block
      if (index % 2 !== 0) {
        // Wrap with bold text style
        const newElement = <Text style={styles.bold}>{element}</Text>;
        newTextArr.push(newElement);
      } else {
        // Simple Text
        const newElement = <Text>{element}</Text>;
        newTextArr.push(newElement);
      }
    });

    return newTextArr;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <Text>{getSmartBold()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cori-oex9kg?file=/src/App.js

---

Edit: If you want the bold-text functionality to be **smarter**, you can check for **stray texts which have dangling** `**`. Code for the same:

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

function getSmartBoldText(text, boldWrapperText = "**") {
  // Split the text around **
  const splitStringArr = text.split(boldWrapperText);

  console.debug(`splitStringArr = `, splitStringArr);

  // Here we will store an array of Text components
  const textComponentsArr = [];

  // Loop over split text
  splitStringArr.forEach((string, index) => {
    // If its an odd element then it is inside **...** block
    // And is not a word surrounded by stray ** (without any closing)
    if (index % 2 !== 0 && index !== splitStringArr.length - 1) {
      // Wrap with bold text style
      const boldText = <Text style={styles.bold}>{string}</Text>;
      textComponentsArr.push(boldText);
    } else {
      // Simple Text

      // If it's stray element, append ** to it
      if (index === splitStringArr.length - 2) {
        string = string + boldWrapperText;
      }

      const normalText = <Text>{string}</Text>;
      textComponentsArr.push(normalText);
    }
  });

  return textComponentsArr;
}

function App() {
  const text =
    "**Lorem ipsum dolor sit, *amet consectetur **adipisicing **elit.";

  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <Text>{getSmartBoldText(text, "**")}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CodeSandbox link for smarter bold-text functionality: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-haslett-238nt3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview)

```
<WebView
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  source={{ html: '<b>Lorem</b> ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.' }}
/>
```

Or any library for secure html insertion