# How to keep HTML tag in react native response?

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, response

I want to keep the HTML tag from response in react native

the response from postman:

```
{
    "enable": true,
    "faq": [
        {
            "answer": "<ol>some text</ol>",
            "question": "question?"
        }
    ]
}
```

code in react native are :

```
doGet(url, additionalHeaders, shouldEncodeURI = true) {
        var containAuthorization = (additionalHeaders !== undefined && additionalHeaders.Authorization !== null);
        const [headers] = this.generateHeaderBody(null, 'application/json', additionalHeaders);
        const encodedUrl = shouldEncodeURI ? encodeURI(url) : url;
        const dataObj = {
            additionalHeaders,
            containAuthorization
        };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(encodedUrl, this.getReqConfig("GET", headers, null)).then(initialResponse => {
                console.log('>>> initial ', JSON.stringify(initialResponse));
                dataObj['initialResponse'] = initialResponse;
                this.responseHandlerGet(url, dataObj, resolve, reject);
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error && error.status) {
                    dataObj['initialResponse'] = error;
                    this.responseHandlerGet(url, dataObj, resolve, reject);
                } else {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        });
    },
```

instead of return `<ol> some text </ol>` the code returning  `some text`

did my code auto delete the HTML tag? or there is some unusual behavior? or even that is normal?

so if want to keep the html tag is there a way of it?

Comment: Do you put it in HTML somehow? Maybe need to HTML encode it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep HTML in your response

then keep your API header

```
"Content-Type": "text/html"
```

You need to pass this

```
const [headers] = this.generateHeaderBody(null, 'text/html', additionalHeaders);
```

Comment: this is still not working for me, but when i load with postman i use ```Content-Type: "application/json" is working fine

Comment: Try to console log response Did you get HTML Tag in consolelog ?? if you are getting HTML tag in response then try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334984/render-html-in-react-native)

Comment: When I do console log after apps get return from service, the html tag suddenly removed automatically from code above